# LXC Error -> Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/proc-diskstats.mount: Permission denied

Tags: debian, systemd, lxc

unfortunately I'm getting a lot of errors like these ones in my debian 8 LXC-container:

```
Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/php5-fpm.service: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/user.slice: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/psa-firewall.service: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/-.mount: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/proc-sys-net.mount: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/proc-sysrq\x2dtrigger.mount: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/sys-devices-virtual-net.mount: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/proc-cpuinfo.mount: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/proc-diskstats.mount: Permission denied
Dec 17 16:34:37 systemd[1]: Failed to reset devices.list on /lxc/103/system.slice/proc-meminfo.mount: Permission denied

Any idea how to solve this?
```